# How to use pg_archivecleanup on Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-9.6

Trying to figure out a proper way to clean old WAL files located in archive directory for point in time recovery purposes.
I know I can use hard-coded name of WAL segment something like this:

```
pg_archivecleanup.exe H:\Backup\pgArchive 0000000100000001000000C1
```

but apparantly I would like to automate this process.

Thank you.

Comment: What is your PITR policy?  How did you pick "0000000100000001000000C1" above?  We cannot tell you how to automate something you have not described.

Comment: I can lose no more than 15 minutes worth of data. "0000000100000001000000C1" is just as an example. Thank you

Comment: That isn't what PITR recovery is.  PITR is "I want to be able to recover the database to the state it was in at anytime between 6 months ago and today".  Do you have some kind of replica/standby, or do you only have a WAL archive?

Comment: Ok, I see. I want to be able to recover the database to the state it was in at anytime between 1 month ago and today. No replica or standby - only WAL archive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automating the process is simple once you know *what* you want to delete.

I can give you a few hints:

- Typically, you want to remove all WAL archives older than the oldest base backup which you want to retain.
- Whenever a base backup is done, PostgreSQL will archive a file called `*.backup`.

  You can use this file as the second argument to `pg_archivecleanup` to remove everything older than that backup.

So to retain the last three backups, you could look at all `*.backup` files, sort them by modification time and find the third youngest file, then use `pg_archivecleanup` with that file as second argument.

Comment: I'd sort by the name of the file (which starts with is a WAL location).  People have been badly burnt assuming modification times will always remain accurate.

Comment: Yes, that is better.

Comment: Well, why use pg_archivecleanup? I can use PowerShell, i guess it will even be more convenient

Comment: Sure. `pg_archivecleanup` doesn't do any magic, it is just fir convenience.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably used a canned solution, rather than trying to create your own.  However, the only open-source canned solution I know of that explicitly says is supports Windows is [pg_probackup](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_probackup), which I have never used.

You say you can lose no more than 15 minutes worth of work.  So without a streaming solution, your "archive_timeout" needs to be less than 15 minutes.  And your archive_command needs to "fsync" (or equivalent) the data on the remote end, which is hard to do and is one spot where the canned solutions can really help.

But it is on the other end of the time policy where things get more difficult, which I think you already know.  Once your second oldest base backup obtains one month of age, you need to delete the oldest base backup and all WAL which was only needed to support that backup.  Identifying the age of the second oldest backup will probably depend on what naming convention you use for them, which is at your discretion.  And pairing that base backup with the corresponding .backup file reliably is also not trivial.  So instead you could go by the second-oldest .backup file, and looking inside that you can identify the base backup corresponding to it (assuming you configured your pg_basebackup correctly--which is not the default configuration).  And then you already know what file to feed to pg_archivecleanup, because that is what you are starting with.  I would look for a canned solution here.

And of course you have to be taking base backups at least once a month to start with, if you want this to work.